# Getting specific folder structure from git

Tags: php, git

i have some files and folder in my git repo. But some of them have a very long path that when i try to synchronize my workspace with git it gives me an error because windows cannot have characters in a path more than 260. Is there a way to pull specific files and folders? for example `*.php` files from `/file/*.php`?

I do not know much from git and also all other tutorials and answers i found here do not work. i even tried the `git git_core.longpathenabled true` but nothing happened.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to pull specific files and folders

Yes, you can use `git filter-branch` and or `git subtree split`

#### Sample code:

## ***`filter-branch`***

```
# Filter the master branch to your directory and remove empty commits
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter YOUR_FOLDER_NAME filter_from_branch
```

This will checkout all your desired files from the given folder to the current directory

---

## ***`subtree split`***

```
git subtree split -P <name-of-folder> -b <name-of-new-branch>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your repository is hosted on Github or similar, you can download the file individually over HTTP, but you obviously will not be able to push changes.

Finally, if your copy of the repo is located in a deeply-nested folder you could move it somewhere like `Users\You\Projects\cloned`.